# Make scroll only if the finger movement is greater than 20% of screen

Tags: react-native

I have a scroll view, which contains list of children(Webview - vertically scrollable). when I try to scroll the Webview vertically, there is a deflection or a small movement in parent - Horizontal direction. I tried passing  messages from the children to the parent for disabling or enabling scroll, which is to slow and not 100% perfect. Is there any way to achieve this through  props in react-native-scrollview for android.

Thnak you.

Comment: Please add a code snippet to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my query, by using `PanResponder` of react-native.

```
componentWillMount() {
  this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
      return Math.abs(gestureState.dx) > minDragWidth;
    },
    onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
      if(!this._swipeDirection) this.checkSwipeDirection(gestureState);
    },
    onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
      this._swipeDirection = null;
    },
  });
}
```

so when a touch event is started, and when the drag continues, these functions will be called respectively.

by checking whether the scroll is horizontal or vertical, we can do the actions.

```
checkSwipeDirection(gestureState) {
  const isHorizontalSwipe = (Math.abs(gestureState.dx) > Math.abs(gestureState.dy * 3)) && 
  (Math.abs(gestureState.vx) > Math.abs(gestureState.vy * 3));

  if(isHorizontalSwipe) {
      this._swipeDirection = "horizontal";
      let index = (gestureState.dx > 0) ? this.state.paginationIndex - 1 : 
this.state.paginationIndex + 1;
      index = (index > 0) ? (index > (this.props.data.length - 1) ? (index - 1) : index) : 0;
      this._scrollToIndex(index, true);
      this.props.doRequiredAction({ index });
  } else {
      this._swipeDirection = "vertical";
  }
}
```

by referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44407955/scrollview-inside-an-panresponder/44509541#44509541) post.